# Where to store face mask at the office

Tags: storage, safety, organization

Here where I live, we are required to go with a face mask where social distancing isn't possible.
So when out on the street I need to wear a mask.

At work, I have my own cubical where no one is nearby so I remove my mask.

The question is: **where do I put the mask after I remove it from my face?** I can't just put it in the drawer, because:

1. The mask could potentially have a lot of germs and make germy everything from the drawer.
2. The stuff in the drawer might have germs which I don't want on my face.

I usually try to carry around a small plastic bag and store it inside, but it usually disappears at some point, either I forget it somewhere, or it just falls out of my pocket.

I thought of just hanging it on the coat hook but I'm not comfortable having it so exposed to the open air.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are live viruses on your desk or in your drawers you should be concerned about transferring them to yourself even if you don't store your mask inside, if the mask is going to transfer bad stuff to your face, then your hands will as well.

Clean your desk, drawer, and work area as often as needed to keep it germ/virus free and then feel free to keep your mask in there. Any place you can put your hands without washing them, is safe to put your mask.

Comment: "Live virus"... Hehe

Answer (score 1):

Use a different mask for each time you put a mask on.

If you use washable masks, take enough for the day in a clean plastic bag (or a clean bag each) and when you are done with the mask for the moment, use a plastic bag to put the used one in. You can put more into the same bag as they will be washed before you use them again.

If you use the disposable masks, dispose of them in a responsible method after one use or with long use after the recommended time, and use a new one for each new need for a mask. Carrying a plastic or paper bag to put them (all) in is a good solution.

In case you have a different kind, bring a box just big enough and place it onto your desk or in a drawer, with your mask in it. Be very careful not to touch the inside with your hands when you put it on after earlier use.

Answer (score 1):

I just fold it and put in my jeans front pocket. It's folded so only the external part of the mask touch the pocket's inside and the part which is on my face isn't exposed to the possible germs/dirt in my pocket.

Sometimes I also put it on my desk, but forgot it there when going out of the office too many times, so pocket is the best option for me.